# Different GCM messages to multiple devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I can send same message to multiple devices.
But i want to send different messages to multiple devices at the same time.
how to do this using GCM?

e.g.
send(reqId[i],message[i])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The only parameter in the GCM server API that contain multiple values is `registration_ids`, which means you can either send the same message to multiple registration IDs in a single request, or send one request for each message when the messages are not the same.